# Spring method Interception - Performance

Tags: spring

I use Spring method interceptors in my project. I am wondering if there would be probable performance issues by introducing method interceptors. At the same time, my understanding is that Spring would create proxy and redefine intercepted methods and make interceptor logic inline in each of the intercepted methods. At runtime, instead of calling the bean, spring uses proxy bean. So with interceptor, additional time taken to create proxy bean itself. Even if more interceptors are added then its a matter of adding more method calls within the same proxy bean's method.  Is this understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the terminology is a little mixed up @LearningHuman, the interceptors are more of a Spring MVC terminology and refer to action that you want to take before the actual controller methods are called - there is a perfomance penalty here, but tends to be negligible compared to the cost of IO involved with streaming data back to the browser, the database round trip time.

I think you are referring to the [Aspects](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html), where Spring creates a dynamic proxy for each bean which has a targeted pointcut, it is not really in-lining the calls in cases where a proxy is created though, so there is a penalty but again if it is in the context of a web application, the IO time will probably be higher than any penalties with additional method calls. 
If performance is a concern, you can use compile time weaving with Aspects, which can inline the calls to the advice atleast.